# How to get City from Google Geocoding using Linq

Tags: .net, json, linq

I have a JSON blob from the Google Geocoding API that contains the name of a city.  I'm just looking for the linq expression to get it out.

JSON:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "277",
           "short_name" : "277",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
           "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings County",
           "short_name" : "Kings County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "11211",
           "short_name" : "11211",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.714232,
           "lng" : -73.9612889
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.7155809802915,
              "lng" : -73.9599399197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.7128830197085,
              "lng" : -73.96263788029151
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Grand St/Bedford Av",
           "short_name" : "Grand St/Bedford Av",
           "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings County",
           "short_name" : "Kings County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "11211",
           "short_name" : "11211",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Grand St/Bedford Av, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.714321,
           "lng" : -73.961151
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.71566998029149,
              "lng" : -73.95980201970849
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.7129720197085,
              "lng" : -73.96249998029151
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Grand St/Bedford Av",
           "short_name" : "Grand St/Bedford Av",
           "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings County",
           "short_name" : "Kings County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "11249",
           "short_name" : "11249",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Grand St/Bedford Av, Brooklyn, NY 11249, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.714684,
           "lng" : -73.961563
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.71603298029149,
              "lng" : -73.9602140197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.7133350197085,
              "lng" : -73.96291198029151
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Bedford Av/Grand St",
           "short_name" : "Bedford Av/Grand St",
           "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings County",
           "short_name" : "Kings County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "11211",
           "short_name" : "11211",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Bedford Av/Grand St, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.71471,
           "lng" : -73.960999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.7160589802915,
              "lng" : -73.95965001970849
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.7133610197085,
              "lng" : -73.9623479802915
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "11211",
           "short_name" : "11211",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "New York",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.7280089,
              "lng" : -73.9207299
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.7008331,
              "lng" : -73.9644697
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.7093358,
           "lng" : -73.9565551
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.7280089,
              "lng" : -73.9207299
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.7008331,
              "lng" : -73.9644697
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "New York",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings County",
           "short_name" : "Kings County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Williamsburg, Brooklyn, NY, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.7251773,
              "lng" : -73.936498
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.6979329,
              "lng" : -73.96984499999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.7064461,
           "lng" : -73.95361629999999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.7251773,
              "lng" : -73.936498
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.6979329,
              "lng" : -73.96984499999999
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings County",
           "short_name" : "Kings County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Kings County, NY, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.739446,
              "lng" : -73.83336509999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.5695637,
              "lng" : -74.0429503
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.6528762,
           "lng" : -73.95949399999999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.739446,
              "lng" : -73.83336509999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.5695637,
              "lng" : -74.0429503
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "New York",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings County",
           "short_name" : "Kings County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Brooklyn, NY, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.739446,
              "lng" : -73.83336509999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.551042,
              "lng" : -74.05663
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.6781784,
           "lng" : -73.94415789999999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.739446,
              "lng" : -73.83336509999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.551042,
              "lng" : -74.05663
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "New York",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York County",
           "short_name" : "New York County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "New York, NY, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.91525559999999,
              "lng" : -73.70027209999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.4959961,
              "lng" : -74.2590879
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.7127837,
           "lng" : -74.0059413
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.91525559999999,
              "lng" : -73.70027209999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.496006,
              "lng" : -74.25573489999999
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "New York, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 45.015865,
              "lng" : -71.85626429999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.4959961,
              "lng" : -79.76214379999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 43.2994285,
           "lng" : -74.21793260000001
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 45.015865,
              "lng" : -71.85626429999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.4960191,
              "lng" : -79.76214379999999
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "United States",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 71.389888,
              "lng" : -66.94976079999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 18.9110642,
              "lng" : 172.4458955
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 37.09024,
           "lng" : -95.712891
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 49.38,
              "lng" : -66.94
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 25.82,
              "lng" : -124.39
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

Here's my criteria:
Given a 'result' in 'results', result 'types' contains 'locality'
For result, I want the item in 'address_components' where 'types' contains 'locality'

UPDATE:

This works, but seems like it could be more concise:

```
if (responseObject["results"].Children().Count() > 0)
        {
            var postalResult = responseObject["results"].Children().FirstOrDefault((result) =>
            {
                return result["types"].Children().Contains("locality");
            });

            if(postalResult !=null)
            {
                var addressComponent = postalResult["address_components"].FirstOrDefault((ac) =>
                {
                    return ac["types"].Children().Contains("locality");
                });

                if(addressComponent != null)
                {
                    cityFromGoogle = addressComponent["long_name"].Value<string>().ToLower();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your json to concrete classes you can work on them easily

```
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Google.Response>(json);

var addresses = resp.results.Where(x => x.address_components.Any(a => a.types.Contains("locality")))
                    .ToList();
```

---

```
public class Google
{
    public class AddressComponent
    {
        public string long_name { get; set; }
        public string short_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bounds
    {
        public Location northeast { get; set; }
        public Location southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public string location_type { get; set; }
        public Bounds viewport { get; set; }
        public Bounds bounds { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public List<AddressComponent> address_components { get; set; }
        public string formatted_address { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going that route, but really just need one piece of info out of the blob.  Don't want to write a bunch of code if NewtonSoft can just handle it for me with linq